# ggplot single generic legend entry for grouped ribbons

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

Using ggplot in R, I'm plotting several grouped lines with an associated interval ribbon around each line. I'd like to split the legend into two parts: one associating each color with the appropriate group, the other explaining the geom elements themselves (a black point/line labeled "Medians", and a generic grey area labeled with "Range"). From reading some other questions I'm guessing the right way to do this is via some dummy aesthetic mapping, but I'm stuck on how to actually implement that to get what I want.

Here's some example data:

```
# Create generic data
test_data <- data.frame(label=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=10),
                        x=rep(1:10, 3),
                        y0=c(1 + runif(10), 4 + runif(10), 7 + runif(10)/2),
                        y1=c(2 + runif(10), 5 + runif(10), 7.5 + runif(10)/2),
                        y2=c(3 + runif(10), 6 + runif(10), 8 + runif(10)/2)
)

# and plot
ggplot(test_data, aes(x=x, y=y1, ymin=y0, ymax=y2, group=label, color=label, fill=label)) + 
  geom_line() + geom_point() + geom_ribbon(alpha=0.25)
```

Current output

[image: Three colored lines with corresponding ribbons, and a legend that groups them all together]

And a mockup of what I'm after:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not the full solution you're looking for, but hopefully a bit helfpul.

```r
library(tidyverse)
test_data <- data.frame(label=rep(c("A", "B", "C"), each=10),
                        x=rep(1:10, 3),
                        y0=c(1 + runif(10), 4 + runif(10), 7 + runif(10)/2),
                        y1=c(2 + runif(10), 5 + runif(10), 7.5 + runif(10)/2),
                        y2=c(3 + runif(10), 6 + runif(10), 8 + runif(10)/2)
)

# and plot
ggplot(test_data, aes(x=x, y=y1, ymin=y0, ymax=y2)) + 
  geom_line(aes(group=label,
                color=label,
                linetype="mean")) + 
  geom_point(aes(group=label,
                 color=label,
                 shape="mean")) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(group=label,
                  fill=label), 
              alpha=0.25)+
  scale_fill_discrete(guide="legend",
                      name="Group")+
  scale_linetype(name=NULL, 
                 guide="legend")+
  scale_shape(name=NULL,
              guide="legend")+
  scale_color_discrete(guide="none")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-12-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>